# Joda-Time Convert String Date Time to Another Format

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have this String `Feb-16-2015 00:00` how do I convert this to another Date Time String with AM/PM ?

Answer (score 5):

First you will need to parse in into a Joda DateTime object, the call `toString(String)` to get a custom format.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse("Feb-16-2015 00:00", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"));
dt.toString("MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a");
```